# Need help starting a proof about uniform convergence and integration.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, uniform-convergence, riemann-integration

> Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a riemann integrable function. For $n\in \mathbb{N}$ let $a=x_0<x_1<...<x_n=b$ be a partition of the interval with $x_k=a+\frac{k}{n}(b-a)$ and $\xi_k\in [x_{k-1},x_{k}]$. Furthermore let a sequence of functions be given by: $$f_n(x)=  \begin{cases} 
>       f(\xi_k),\ x\in (x_{k-1},x_{k}); k\in \{1,...,n \}  \\
> f(x), \ x=x_k; \ k\in \{0,...,n \}
>    \end{cases}
> $$
> Prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_a^bf_n(x)dx=\int_a^bf(x)dx$ and also that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(\xi_k)=\int_a^bf(x)dx. $$

This is probably the most dense question I've come across in analysis and I'm not sure where to begin exactly so I'd appreciate some tips. In a different question I managed to prove that if arbitrary integrable sequence $f_n$ converges uniformly to a $f$ then the equality involving the integrals holds true. So I was thinking of looking at  $f_n$ to see if it converges uniformly and then maybe go on to see if the second equality holds but I'm not sure.

Comment: The integrals of the $f_n$ are Riemann sums.  Write it out and you will see it.

Comment: The final thing you want to prove wasn't copied correctly.  It   should read this way: $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(\xi_k)=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf(x)dx.$$ This famously exhibits the integral as an "average."

Comment: You are focussed on *uniform convergence* to help you out here.  But, in general, this sequence will not converge uniformly since you have assumed only that $f$ is Riemann integrable.  So do follow the other advice and think "limit of Riemann sums"  and forget about uniform convergence.  [Incidently a sequence $\{f_n\}$ of step functions that is uniformly convergent, can converge only to a regulated function.  Not all Riemann integrable functions are regulated.]